# Returning the proper child type when calling inherited parent method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Let's say I have this parent class `Vector2` defined as follows:

```
function Vector2 (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
Vector2.prototype.add = function(vec) {
  console.log(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(this));
  if (vec instanceof Vector2)
    return new Vector2(this.x + vec.x, this.y + vec.y);
  throw "This operation can only be performed on another Vector2. Recieved " + typeof vec;
};
```

And an extension of `Vector2` called `Size` that should inherit all the functional goodness of its parent, with the aditional ability to reference `x` and `y` as `w` and `h` respectively, like so:

```
function Size(x,y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
Size.prototype = new Vector2;
Size.prototype.constructor = Size;
Size.prototype._super = Vector2.prototype;
Object.defineProperties(Size.prototype, {
  'w': {
    get: function() {
      return this.x;
    },
    set: function(w) {
      this.x = w;
    }
  },
  'h': {
    get: function() {
      return this.y;
    },
    set: function(h) {
      this.y = h;
    }
  }
});
```

Finally, I have a code snippet that creates two new instances of `Size`, adds them together, and attempts to read from the `w` property like so:

```
var s1 = new Size(2, 4);
var s2 = new Size(3, 7);
var s3 = s1.add(s2);
console.log(s3.w);
// 'undefined' because s3 is an instance Vector2, not Size
```

How can I modify `Vector2`'s `add` method to create a new instance of *whatever* the current class is rather than a generic one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your getter code: instead of `self` you need to use `this`.

Then you can call the correct constructor with:

```
return new this.constructor(this.x + vec.x, this.y + vec.y);
```

NB: You could also use `vec.constructor`, it all depends what you want to happen when you add a Size object to a Vector object. It seems more intuitive to me that the source object (on which the `add` method is applied) determines the class of the returned object. If you feel the added object should determine the returned object's class, then use `vec` instead of `this`.

Comment: Good of your to reject it. I just tested and learned something. I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: No problem. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this might be what you're looking for.

`return new vec.constructor(this.x + vec.x, this.y + vec.y);`

Use the `constructor` of what is passed to add method to create your returned object.

You're also passing `this` to your `new Vector2( this, ... )` erroneously.